# How to generate a link user can click in the email that goes to the NodeJS backend?

Tags: node.js, api, express, nodemailer

A user receives an email sent using NodeMailer with a clickable link. Now, when the user clicks the link, it should make a request to the backend with the email of the user and a hash embedded in the link. How do I do this?

I am using MySQL, NodeJS, ExpressJS for my backend and NodeMailer for sending emails.

Comment: What's wrong with creating an endpoint with params ?

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa pardon my noobness, what is an endpoint with params?

Comment: a endpoint with params can be url params or query string. ex: `/users/${id}` or `/users?id=${id}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- While creating the node mailer template you will have access to the user email, add that email and hash to the hyper link.
- Create a get route in your server **"/users/:email/:hash"**.
- When user clicks on the link you can access the **email - req.params.email** & **hash - req.params.hash**